# How to write a recursive Java method to print a triangle of numbers

Tags: java, recursion

How would I write a recursive Java method with the header *recursiveMethod(int x, int max)* such that if I were to call it with *recursiveMethod(1, 10)* it would print the following:

1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999

I know how to do this with loops but can't figure out how to do it with recursion. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does your loop version look like? Just translate the counter of the loop into an argument of the recursive function, increase it on each call and break the recursion according to some condition.

Comment: *Have a go*. Even if it doesn't work. Then think about why it doesn't work. And if you can't figure out why what you've tried doesn't work, post your attempt here.

Comment: Here's a beginning which might help you `public class Main {
    void recursiveMethod(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        a++;
        if(a==b)
            return;
        else
            recursiveMethod(a, b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().recursiveMethod(1, 10);
    }
}
`

Comment: This works

public class HelloWorld{


    static void recursiveMethod(int x, int max){
        if(x == max){
            return;
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            recursiveMethod(x+1,max);
        }
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
         recursiveMethod(1,10);
     
     }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion means you must have a base case. Formulate the base case first:

```
if (a==b)
  return;
```

The above code means that recursion will stop if a==b. We put the recursion into a trivial recursive method which initially gives the wrong output but it compiles and it is recursive:

```
public class Main {
    void recursiveMethod(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        a++;
        if(a==b)
            return;
        else
            recursiveMethod(a, b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().recursiveMethod(1, 10);
    }
}
```

Now we can fine-tune the code to make the correct output:

```
public class Main {
    void recursiveMethod(int a, int b) {
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
          System.out.print(a);
        System.out.println();
        a++;
        if(a==b)
            return;
        else
            recursiveMethod(a, b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().recursiveMethod(1, 10);
    }
}
```